# Does the Patent D-120891 hold 2 different creations/inventions?

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [USD120891](https://www.google.com/patents/USD120891)

I have 2 pictures with this very same patent number D-120891.  The small pictures appear to be of the Catholic Religion.  Would this be of the same Inventor - Charlotte Neuhardt? The designer/inventor of the dress holding patent D-120891.

Answer (score 1):

its slightly unclear what you are asking, if I go with word 'US' here just designate country and D states design patent and number is serial number of the issued patent. Therefore its only one patent not two.

To be short USD120891. and D-120891 are same.